# Profiling user-defined methods in android

Tags: android, methods, profiling, user-defined

Can't I use profiling for user-defined methods in android? I searched for my method name in the 'Find:' box of the profiling window. But, no use. I am using Eclipse 3.7.2 in Ubuntu 12.04. Any answers would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: some methods can profile, but some can't, I don't know why

Answer (score 1):

Profiling in VM-based languages, such as Java, is somewhat tricky, especially when using a sampling profiler. The VM occasionally decides to inline some methods, which may remove them completely from the view of the profiler, or reduce the time that the profiler thinks is spent in them. I have mentioned some general caveats of sampling profilers in [an older answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9344922/507519).

Instead of searching for this specific method, you could try searching for methods that call it, or for methods that are called by it. Hopefully, you will be able to discern enough information to figure out if your method is a performance concern.

Unless you provide more information on your code and *how* exactly you are profiling your application, it is difficult to be more specific. You should at least mention if you are using an instrumenting or a sampling profiler...