# Why is this method a hot spot?

Tags: java, performance, optimization, visualvm

I'm writing a (simple!) linear algebra library. In the implementation of [matrix multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication), a [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) performance sample is telling me that the algorithm spends 85% of its time ("self time", specifically) in the following method when multiplying large matrices (5k x 120k):

```
public double next() {
    double result;

    if(hasNext())
        result = vis[i++].next();
    else
        throw new IllegalStateException("No next value");

    return result;
}
```

Without going into too much detail (sorry, I can't share more code), this method is the `next()` method of an "iterator" for the matrix. (You can think of the class this method lives in as a row iterator made up of individual column iterators, which are stored in `vis`.) I'm not surprised that this method gets called a lot since it's an iterator, but I *am* surprised that the program spends a lot of its time *in* this method. This method doesn't do too much, so why is it spending its time here?

Here are the specific questions I'm asking:

1. Is there some "gotcha" of VisualVM I'm hitting? For example, could the JIT be confusing VisualVM in some way that's causing VisualVM to attribute time to the wrong method?
2. Why would the program be spending its time here? The method just doesn't do too much. In particular, I don't think cache effects explain this problem because the `vis` array is much smaller than the data of the matrices being multiplied.

In case it's useful, here's a [jad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAD_%28JAva_Decompiler%29) disassembly of the method I pasted above:

```
public double next()
{
    double result;
    if(hasNext())
//*   0    0:aload_0         
//*   1    1:invokevirtual   #88  <Method boolean hasNext()>
//*   2    4:ifeq            32
        result = vis[i++].next();
//    3    7:aload_0         
//    4    8:getfield        #42  <Field VectorIterator[] vis>
//    5   11:aload_0         
//    6   12:dup             
//    7   13:getfield        #28  <Field int i>
//    8   16:dup_x1          
//    9   17:iconst_1        
//   10   18:iadd            
//   11   19:putfield        #28  <Field int i>
//   12   22:aaload          
//   13   23:invokeinterface #72  <Method double VectorIterator.next()>
//   14   28:dstore_1        
    else
//*  15   29:goto            42
        throw new IllegalStateException("No next value");
//   16   32:new             #89  <Class IllegalStateException>
//   17   35:dup             
//   18   36:ldc1            #91  <String "No next value">
//   19   38:invokespecial   #93  <Method void IllegalStateException(String)>
//   20   41:athrow          
    return result;
//   21   42:dload_1         
//   22   43:dreturn         
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help guys!

Comment: I guess it really depends on the hasNext() and next() calls since we don't know the underlying objects I cant assume they are O(1) and the method should be pretty fast, that hasNext() could be going around the sun 1000x for all we know

Comment: @RuntimeError, "self time" *should* only include time spent inside the method itself, so the `hasNext()` and the sub-`next()` calls *should* have nothing to do with the self time attributed to this method, as far as I know. (Please correct me if you know differently!)

Comment: Is `next` calling itself (recursive)? That would be a good reason why it takes time if the recursion is deep...

Comment: @assylias No, it does not. The `next()` method that this `next()` method calls is in a different class. Great point, though.

Comment: @sigpwned Your method is fairly short so it probably gets inlined at some stage, [which could confuse the profiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130277/why-visualvm-sampler-does-not-provide-full-information-about-cpu-load-method-ti).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured out that this method looked like a hotspot because VisualVM was being instructed to ignore methods from the JRE in its profiling. The time being spent in those "ignored" methods was (ostensibly) being rolled into the self time of the topmost non-ignored entry of the call stack.

Below is the settings screen in VisualVM, including the "Do not profile packages" setting that was making the data wrong. To adjust the "ignore class" settings, you have to (1) click the "Settings" checkbox highlighted in red, then (2) adjust the classes setting highlighted in blue.

[image: VisualVM Settings Screen]

Depending on what you're doing, it probably makes sense at least not to ignore the `java.*` and `javax.*` packages.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know VisualVM from experience.

First determine if its instrumenting the bytecode to gather statistics. If so, look no further - instrumenting a short method always overinflates its self time (measuring the time and incrementing the statistics counter costs more time than the method itself).

But its always possible that the iterator consumes more time than the calculation itself. Imagine just summing up a matrix. Adding a float value to a local sum variable costs a lot less time than invoking a method, checking an invariant and finally accessing the array.

Comment: I just checked the documentation of VisualVM. It IS an instrumenting profiler.

Comment: However, I believe I'm using it in "sampling" mode, which means it should be "freezing" the CPU periodically (probably tens or hundreds of times per second) and then seeing what happens to be running on each thread in that process at that time. That's a fairly unobtrusive approach (from experience), and should not arbitrarily inflate the time spent in that method, IMO.

Comment: Well I'm not familiar with VisualVM, but the documentation says "When analyzing application performance, VisualVM *instruments all of the methods* of the profiled application" under CPU profiling (http://visualvm.java.net/profiler.html). Not sure if thats what you are doing or if you use another option?

Comment: There's a "sampler" option I'm using that is different from the "profiler" option, which is why I believe it's sampling. It doesn't appear to be covered by the online guide, which is unfortunate. You can see a screenshot of the option [here](http://i.imgur.com/7lI5QXR.png) for reference.

Comment: Sampling does not use instrumentation.

Comment: @TomasHurka Thanks for repeating the obvious

Answer (score 1):

Forget the profiler. Just pause the darn thing a few times and examine the stack. If 85% of the time goes into that routine, then chances are 85% on each pause that you will see exactly where it is in that routine, and exactly where it comes from.
You can even see where it is in the process of multiplying the matrices.
Thousands of samples won't tell you that.

My own sense is that calling that function, then doing `hasNext`, then doing `Next` on *every single element* is going to be a lot slower than `i++`.